# Stop Javascript from running with only access to css

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on modifying a template from the 3rd party software Inksoft. I am able to access the header file on 'all pages' and have a script that is pointing to an additional css file that I am using to modify layout, fonts, etc.

My client really hates this zoom function that is being used on images. It is being done using the mojozoom js script.

Can you guys think of any way I can prevent this effect from happening on rollover? To stop the script from running or somehow hide the zoomed image that pops up via css?

Here is a screen shot of what I have access to via Inksoft: http://www.moonandfox.com/ex1.png

And here is the page in question: http://stores.inksoft.com/Trevor_Friedrich/Products

Comment: Of course you can do `.mojozoom_imgctr, .mojozoom_marker { display: none; }`, but it would be much easier if you could prevent that script from loading. Are you sure there's no toggle option somewhere in the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the CSS classes that are showing up.

```
.mojozoom_marker, .mojozoom_imgctr {
  display: none;
}
```

`mojozoom_marker` is the box (with crosshairs) that shows up within the thumbnail image.  `mojozoom_imgctr` is the enlarged, "zoomed-in" version that appears on the side of the image, on hover.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't see that .mojozoom_imgctr class in there before. 
Thanks again!